# Understanding OOM killer logs

Tags: linux, docker, cgroup, oom-killer

I run some processes inside docker container and I use memory  limitation for this container. Sometimes some processes inside docker container got killed by OOM killer. I see that in syslog file:

```
beam.smp invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0xd0, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
beam.smp cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
CPU: 0 PID: 20908 Comm: beam.smp Not tainted 3.13.0-36-generic #63~precise1-Ubuntu
Hardware name: Xen HVM domU, BIOS 4.2.amazon 05/23/2014
 ffff880192ca6c00 ffff880117ebfbe8 ffffffff817557fe 0000000000000007
 ffff8800ea1e9800 ffff880117ebfc38 ffffffff8174b5b9 ffff880100000000
 000000d08137dd08 ffff880117ebfc38 ffff88010c05e000 0000000000000000
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff817557fe>] dump_stack+0x46/0x58
 [<ffffffff8174b5b9>] dump_header+0x7e/0xbd
 [<ffffffff8174b64f>] oom_kill_process.part.5+0x57/0x2d4
 [<ffffffff81075295>] ? has_ns_capability_noaudit+0x15/0x20
 [<ffffffff8115b709>] ? oom_badness.part.4+0xa9/0x140
 [<ffffffff8115ba27>] oom_kill_process+0x47/0x50
 [<ffffffff811bee4c>] mem_cgroup_out_of_memory+0x28c/0x2b0
 [<ffffffff811c122b>] mem_cgroup_oom_synchronize+0x23b/0x270
 [<ffffffff811c0ac0>] ? memcg_charge_kmem+0xf0/0xf0
 [<ffffffff8115be08>] pagefault_out_of_memory+0x18/0x90
 [<ffffffff81747e91>] mm_fault_error+0xb9/0xd3
 [<ffffffff81766267>] ? __do_page_fault+0x317/0x570
 [<ffffffff81766495>] __do_page_fault+0x545/0x570
 [<ffffffff8101361d>] ? __switch_to+0x16d/0x4d0
 [<ffffffff810a5d3d>] ? set_next_entity+0xad/0xd0
 [<ffffffff8175df1e>] ? __schedule+0x38e/0x700
 [<ffffffff817664da>] do_page_fault+0x1a/0x70
 [<ffffffff81762648>] page_fault+0x28/0x30
Task in /docker/a4d47fb7bbc8a2bbc172bd26085c4509364b1b7eec61439669e08e281b181a0b killed as a result of limit of /docker/a4d47fb7bbc8a2bbc172bd26085c4509364b1b7eec61439669e08e281b181a0b
memory: usage 229600kB, limit 262144kB, failcnt 5148
memory+swap: usage 524288kB, limit 524288kB, failcnt 19118
kmem: usage 0kB, limit 18014398509481983kB, failcnt 0
Memory cgroup stats for /docker/a4d47fb7bbc8a2bbc172bd26085c4509364b1b7eec61439669e08e281b181a0b: cache:0KB rss:229600KB rss_huge:8192KB mapped_file:0KB writeback:3336KB swap:294688KB inactive_anon:114980KB active_anon:114620KB inactive_file:0KB active_file:0KB unevictable:0KB
[ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes swapents oom_score_adj name
[ 9537]     0  9537     8740      712      21     1041             0 my_init
[13097]     0 13097       48        3       3       16             0 runsvdir
[13098]     0 13098       42        4       3       19             0 runsv
[13100]     0 13100       42        4       3       38             0 runsv
[13101]     0 13101       42        4       3       17             0 runsv
[13102]     0 13102       42        4       3        4             0 runsv
[13103]     0 13103       42        4       3       39             0 runsv
[13104]     0 13104     4779      243      15       60             0 cron
[13105]     0 13105     8591      601      22     1129             0 ruby
[13107]     0 13107    20478      756      43      560             0 syslog-ng
[13108]     0 13108    11991      642      28     1422             0 ruby
[20826]     0 20826     4467      249      14       63             0 run
[20827]     0 20827     1101      144       8       29             0 huobi
[20878]     0 20878     3708      172      13       48             0 run_erl
[20879]     0 20879   249481    57945     321    72955             0 beam.smp
[20969]     0 20969     1846       83       9       27             0 inet_gethost
[20970]     0 20970     3431      173      12       33             0 inet_gethost
[20977]     0 20977     1101      127       8       25             0 sh
[20978]     0 20978     1074      125       8       23             0 memsup
[20979]     0 20979     1074       68       7       23             0 cpu_sup
[ 5446]     0  5446     8462      217      22       81             0 cron
[ 5451]     0  5451     1101      127       8       26             0 sh
[ 5453]     0  5453     1078       68       8       22             0 sleep
[10898]     0 10898     8462      217      22       81             0 cron
[10899]     0 10899     8462      216      22       80             0 cron
[10900]     0 10900     1101      127       7       26             0 sh
[10901]     0 10901     1101      127       8       25             0 sh
[10902]     0 10902     1078       68       7       22             0 sleep
[10903]     0 10903     1078       68       8       22             0 sleep
Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 20911 (beam.smp) score 1001 or sacrifice child
Killed process 20977 (sh) total-vm:4404kB, anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:508kB
```

I know that `beam.smp` process consumes memory resources very aggressively. So the very first line of log `beam.smp invoked oom-killer` does make sense.

But I'm confused about last 2 lines of log. It says `Kill process 20911 (beam.smp)`, but processs with PID 20911 does not exist inside this cgroup (list of processes dumped to log too). And last line says `Killed process 20977 (sh)` (and this PID presents in cgroup).
We were about to kill `beam.smp`, but finally killed `sh`. What does it mean?

Answer (score 10):

The OOM killer decided to kill another process.

The message did state:

> ```
> Kill process 20911 .... or sacrifice child
> ```

It decided to kill the child with pid 20977, a shell script that was spawned by the process.

If you want Linux to always kill the task which caused the out of memory condition, set the sysctl `vm.oom_kill_allocating_task` to 1.

---

From the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt):

> This enables or disables killing the OOM-triggering task in
>   out-of-memory situations.
>
> If this is set to zero, the OOM killer will scan through the entire
>   tasklist and select a task based on heuristics to kill.  This normally
>   selects a rogue memory-hogging task that frees up a large amount of
>   memory when killed.
>
> If this is set to non-zero, the OOM killer simply kills the task that
>   triggered the out-of-memory condition.  This avoids the expensive
>   tasklist scan.
>
> If panic_on_oom is selected, it takes precedence over whatever value
>   is used in oom_kill_allocating_task.
>
> The default value is 0.